# Node, express, body parser, problem with post app - not working?

Tags: node.js, express, post, body-parser

I have problem with app post, I thought it was because of bodyParser, but I tried all the combinations I found on the internet and it still doesn't work  and it is not even ...res.send("Something")... in functional, does anyone know how solve my problem? thank you

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

    var firstName = req.body.fName;
    var lastName = req.body.lName;
    var email = req.body.email;


    console.log(firstName, lastName, email);
    res.send("Something");

    
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
})
```

I'm trying to find a solution to my problem, or at least people who deal with similar topics, who I can work

Comment: *doesn't work* is not a description of the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to point out that saying it doesn't work does not define your problem. I'm answering assuming you have set up your nodejs server properly.

Firstly, after you run `node app.js`, if you still do not receive a "Something" response when sending a post request to http://localhost:3000/, check if you have posted to the correct URL.

Secondly your code should be like below to use request body.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Finally, you need to add `Content-Type: application/json` to the header of the request when sending requests. I hope it was helpful. Good Luck :)

Comment: Not sure why JSON would be needed here...? Urlencoded is the default the browser will use for forms anyway...

Comment: @CherryDT I didn't see anyone using a basic html forms for years

Comment: @CherryDT req.body format is JSON and using body-parser allows you to access req.body from within routes and use that data. So, JSON is required to be able to read req.body on nodejs server.

Comment: @mymz Why? Nowhere in the question does it say they are sending JSON. We would need to see how the endpoint is actually called before making these assumptions.